# Convert C# datetime to Json serialized Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net-2.0, json.net

i need some help here

I am trying to make an API call by sending a json object to it.

but i am struggling to convert C# datetime to proper json format.

Here is my Sample Code.

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("example.com");

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";

httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{

    string json = "{\"ReferenceNumber\":\"Testing OAKLAND\",\"CustomerNotes\":\"Testing\",\"DeliveryDate\":" + "Date(" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks + ")" +
                         ",\"OrderLineItems\":[{\"ItemEntityId\":14771,\"Quantity\":2}]}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{

    string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    Response.Write(responseText);
    Response.End();
    }
```

Please guide me how to format datetime in json and do u guys think that json this json object is fine?? I am Using .NET 2.0 Framework

Comment: JSON does not have a standard date format, so there are several different formats commonly used.  What date format is the API expecting?  Is there documentation for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use serialization instead. It will handle any escaping and converting you need to do.

For .NET 2.0 you don't have the luxury of anonymous types, so you will have to create a model class for the data you want to serialize:

```
public class OrderModel {
  private string _referenceNumber;
  public string ReferenceNumber {
    get { return _referenceNumber; }
    set { _referenceNumber = value; }
  }
  ...
  class OrderItem {
    private int _itemEntityId;
    public int ItemEntityId {
      get { return _itemEntityId; }
      set { _itemEntityId; }
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

You can use the `SerializeObject` method of [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new OrderModel {
  ReferenceNumber = "Testing OAKLAND",
  CustomerNotes = "Testing",
  DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now,
  OrderLineItems = new List<OrderItem>() {
    new OrderItem { ItemEntityId = 14771, Quantity = 2 }
  }
});
```

I know this seems like more code, but believe me it will save you a lot of hassle in the future and for any other developers looking at your code.

Comment: BTW i forgot to mention i am Using .NET 2.0 so need things working in that framework.

Comment: Thanks,  but you can not user System.web.Extension.dll in 2.0 atleast i dont have it available from VS2012, and i am using Json.NET and still i am not able to use JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: If you are using Json.NET then you don't need the JavaScriptSerializer. Updated code. I can't remember if you can use object initialisers in C# 2.0, but just create the model class as you normally would instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Date is now formated and json object looks like this now 
{"CustomerNotes":"Testing","DeliveryDate":"2013-07-30T12:32:04.4826274+05:00","ReferenceNumber":"Testing OAKLAND","OrderItem":[{"ItemEntityId":14771,"Quantity":2}]}     but api still not accepting and thorws some weird error saying Model is invalid.. thanks for your help so far. :)